# R: matrix of string of integers to array of integer counts

Tags: arrays, r, matrix

I have a character matrix of strings of comma-separated integers:

```
> mat<-matrix(c(NA,"1",NA,"2,1","3","1,3,3"),nrow=2)
> mat
     [,1] [,2]  [,3]   
[1,] NA   NA    "3"    
[2,] "1"  "2,1" "1,3,3"
```

I desire to have an output which is a numeric array where the z indices represent the counts of the integers in the matrix:

```
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   1    1    1 

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   1    NA

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   NA   1
[2,]   NA   NA   2
```

How may I accomplish this?

To have an idea of the scale of the data, the final array will be of dimensions ~20,000 x 2,000 x 200, and the matrix will be the first two dimensions of the array (20,000 x 2,000).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This uses a loop and probably won't be the most efficient solution:

```
mat<-matrix(c(NA,"1",NA,"2,1","3","1,3,3"),nrow=2)

#split the strings
temp <- strsplit(mat, ",", fixed=TRUE)

#unique values
levels <- na.omit(unique(do.call(c, temp)))

#convert to factors and use table
temp <- t(sapply(temp, function(x) table(factor(x, levels=levels))))

#make it an array
array(temp, c(nrow(mat), ncol(mat), length(levels)))
# , , 1
# 
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    0    0    0
# [2,]    1    1    1
# 
# , , 2
# 
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    0    0    0
# [2,]    0    1    0
# 
# , , 3
# 
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    0    0    1
# [2,]    0    0    2
```

### Edit:

This avoids applying `table` and `factor` in a loop and should be faster:

```
temp <- strsplit(mat, ",", fixed=TRUE)

id <- rep(seq_along(temp), sapply(temp, length))
temp <- factor(do.call(c, temp))
array(t(table(temp, id)), c(nrow(mat), ncol(mat), length(levels(temp))))
```

Comment: Is there a away to replace sapply with mclapply here?

Comment: Of course you can do that. You'll just need `do.call(rbind, temp)` afterwards.